# git: smudge only run when textconv is enabled

Tags: git

i am having a hard time figuring out when `smudge` filter runs exactly; i am using both filter (with `smudge`) and diff (with `textconv`) drivers; and i want to generate a diff between `HEAD~` and `HEAD`:

```
git diff HEAD~ HEAD
```

my working dir is clean; if i comment `textconv` in `.git/config` then `smudge` filter does not run;

---

it seems that:

`smudge` filter is run only when `textconv` is enabled;

my question is simple; i want to know if this is true;

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple settings here and it is hard to tell from your question which ones you are using.

The smudge filter runs when:

- there is a smudge filter listed for the file, and
- Git is copying a file from the index to the work-tree, or (with the new `--textconv` options to `git show` and `git cat-file`) showing the committed or index form of a file.

The cache for the smudge filter is the work-tree copy of the file.  If the work-tree copy is up to date—or even if Git simply *believes* it is up to date, even if it's not actually up to date—the smudge filter will not run.

The textconv filter runs when Git is extracting a committed or index file for purposes of feeding it to an internal or external diff.  If there is a smudge filter required to perform this extraction, Git will run the smudge filter.  (I'm not sure if Git will use the work-tree copy as a cached entry if it appears to be up to date, but it might be sensible to do that.  This would affect any measurement of using the smudge filter when doing textconv operations.)

[The cache for the textconv filter is user-definable, and defaults to disabled](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes):

> Because text conversion can be slow, especially when doing a large number of them with `git log -p`, Git provides a mechanism to cache the output and use it in future diffs. To enable caching, set the "cachetextconv" variable in your diff driver’s config. ...

See [the gitattributes documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) for the rest of this description and some advice on when to enable textconv caching and whether to define a text conversion or use an external diff.